# ES6 default values not available in function.arguments?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have this ES6 function declaration and invocation:

```
function myFunction (arg1, arg2 = "bob") {
  console.log("arguments", arguments);
}

myFunction(1);
```

...the `console.log()` statement shows only one argument with a value of "1". "bob" is nowhere to be seen. Is this expected and/or desired behavior? I would expect that default values would be available in the `arguments` object. If not, is there a way to dynamically get all arguments + defaults in some other manner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated my answer, just for fun... have a look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is expected and desired. The `arguments` object is a list of the values that were passed into the function, nothing else.

It is not implicily linked to the parameter variables (that get assigned the default values), like it was in sloppy mode.

> Is there a way to dynamically get all arguments + defaults in some other manner?

No. What parameters you have and whether they have default initialisers is static, you don't need to do anything here dynamically. You can do `Object.assign([], arguments, [arg1, arg2])` for your example function.

Comment: Thanks. So does that mean there's no way to get an object of "passed arguments and defaults where arguments are not passed"?

Comment: The `Object.assign` solution is nice - I was envisaging checking lengths of arrays and splicing etc to handle this.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: The simple alternative here is `var args = Array.from(arguments); args[1] = arg2;`

Comment: Right.  I still prefer the one in your answer - it looks more easily expandable to cover more  args etc, and doesn't care which ones are optional

Answer (score 1):

As you know by now, there is no native method to get both "passed arguments AND defaults where arguments are not passed". But there is a workaround:

This function (that I found [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-arguments)) gets all parameters of a given function:

```
function getArgs(func) {
  var args = func.toString().match(/function\s.*?\(([^)]*)\)/)[1];
  return args.split(',').map(function(arg) {
  return arg.replace(/\/\*.*\*\//, '').trim();
}).filter(function(arg) {
  return arg;
 });
};
```

So, combining this function with the `arguments` of your function `myFunction`, we can get an array that has what you want:

```
function myFunction (arg1, arg2 = "bob") {
    var thisArguments = arguments;
    console.log(getArgs(myFunction, thisArguments));
};

function getArgs(func, argums) {
    var args = func.toString().match(/function\s.*?\(([^)]*)\)/)[1];
    var argsArray = args.split(',').map(function(arg) {
       return arg.replace(/\/\*.*\*\//, '').trim();
    }).filter(function(arg) {
      return arg;
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < argsArray.length; i++){
      argsArray[i] += " (default)";
    }
    var defaults = argsArray.slice(argums.length);
    argums = Array.prototype.slice.call(argums);
    return argums.concat(defaults);
};
```

Now, we can see the information in the console calling `myFunction`:

**1. Passing more arguments than parameters**

This will return only the arguments.

```
myFunction("foo", "bar", "baz");
//returns: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

**2. Passing less arguments than parameters**

Will return the arguments and the remainder parameters as default, as you want (I added "default" to each string).

```
myFunction("foo");
//returns ["foo", "arg2 = "bob" (default)"]
```

**3. Passing no arguments**

This will return all the parameters.

```
myFunction();
//returns ["arg1 (default)", "arg2 = "bob" (default)"]
```

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/25jxrkm8/1/

Comment: That's kind of interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting update, too, though it appears that the result doesn't have the actual values of the variables in a terribly actionable format, right?